# Why am I unable to resume a crawl in Srapy?

Tags: scrapy

I tried to resume a crawl i had performed (and later tried to resume) with the command:

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
```

But it doesn't resume and instead shows the following log output:

```
2013-07-17 12:36:57+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.5 started (bot: thesentientspider)
2013-07-17 12:36:58+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: AutoThrottle, LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-07-17 12:36:59+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, RandomUserAgentMiddleWare, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-07-17 12:36:59+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-07-17 12:36:59+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: MongoDBPipeline
2013-07-17 12:36:59+0530 [zomatoSpider] INFO: Spider opened
2013-07-17 12:36:59+0530 [zomatoSpider] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-07-17 12:36:59+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6033
2013-07-17 12:36:59+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6090
2013-07-17 12:36:59+0530 [zomatoSpider] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.zomato.com/hyderabad/restaurants> from <GET http://www.zomato.com/hyderabad/restaurants/>
2013-07-17 12:37:00+0530 [zomatoSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.zomato.com/hyderabad/restaurants> (referer: None)
2013-07-17 12:37:00+0530 [zomatoSpider] DEBUG: slot: www.zomato.com | conc: 1 | delay: 1000 ms | latency:  283 ms | size:158792 bytes
2013-07-17 12:37:00+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Next page URL: http://www.zomato.com/hyderabad/restaurants?page=2
2013-07-17 12:37:00+0530 [zomatoSpider] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-07-17 12:37:00+0530 [zomatoSpider] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 619,
     'downloader/request_count': 2,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 23308,
     'downloader/response_count': 2,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 17, 7, 7, 0, 496989),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 10,
     'log_count/INFO': 4,
     'request_depth_max': 1,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued/disk': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued/disk': 2,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 17, 7, 6, 59, 463810)}
2013-07-17 12:37:00+0530 [zomatoSpider] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

This is my spider code (the requests look serializable to me, if i am not mistaken).
Settings: http://pastebin.com/CUsf4sTJ
Spider: http://pastebin.com/at98Qhjh

What am i doing wrong? Any way i can salvage the crawl?

Comment: May be a directory permission issue, try to set 777 on `crawls` dir.

Comment: Does it get into `parse_restaurant_details` in line 54-55 ?

Comment: @XuJiawan, you mean in the second run or the first? Things worked fine the first time and i was able to scrape thousands of items in the first run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inherited from `BaseSpider`, which just crawls the `start_urls`. You should inherit `CrawlSpider`(scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider).

Comment: Yup, sounds right...i had to put in additional logic to store and resume from the last start URL.